# Looking for Unix tool/script that, given an input path, will compress every batch of uncompressed 100MB text files into a single gzip file

Tags: unix, batch, compression

I have a dump of thousands of small text files (1-5MB) large, each containing lines of text. I need to "batch" them up, so that each batch is of a fixed size - say 100MB, and compress that batch.

Now that batch could be:

1. A single file that is just a 'cat' of the contents of the individual text files, or
2. Just the individual text files themselves

Caveats:

1. unix `split -b` will not work here as I need to keep lines of text intact. Using the `lines` option is a bit complicated as there is a large variance in the number of bytes in each line.
2. The files need not be a fixed size strictly, as long as it's within 5% of the requested size
3. The lines are critical, and should not be lost: I need to confirm that the input made its way to output without loss - what rolling checksum (something like CRC32, BUT better/"stronger" in face of collisions)

A script should do nicely, but this seems like a task someone has done before, and it would be nice to see some code (preferably python or ruby) that does atleast something similar.

Comment: Would a Bash script be good for you? Do the small files need to be stored in a given order?

Comment: No specific order. I would prefer as little intermediate files as possible. My naive algorithm was along the lines of "{get a bunch of files, keep on summing their size until you are jus around your split limit, cat + compress those files into one file with a numeric suffix, inc numeric suffix}, repeat steps until <bunch of files> is empty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script, will create compressed packages of files within the given directory. You invoke it like:

```
script.sh directorypath
```

It uses a simple/naive algorithm (just like the one you described):

- Count all files.
- Start reading all files recursively.
- Get size, ls entry and checksum (SHA1) of each file. (Store ls entry in manifest.txt  and checksum in checksum.txt).
- If size has just passed limit use the manifest.txt list to create a compressed tar (which includes the manifest and checksum files too).
- Create temporary directory and decompress just created tar.
- Calculate new checksums of just extracted files.
- Compare with stored checksums.
- If at least one checksum is different, exit with an error.
- Otherwise, check if delete option is enabled, if so, remove source files.
- Repeat until there no more files.

Its output is like:

```
Reading files...
15898 849 ../out/f068715p.jpg
Creating package (pack18.tar.gz) with 849 files, using 100078420 bytes...
tar: Removing leading `../' from member names
Preparing to verify package...
Creating new checksums...
Comparing checksums...
Package verification OK.
Deleting temporary verification directory...
Reading files...
16731 833 ../out/f069111c.jpg
Creating package (pack19.tar.gz) with 833 files, using 100004735 bytes...
tar: Removing leading `../' from member names
Preparing to verify package...
Creating new checksums...
Comparing checksums...
Package verification OK.
Deleting temporary verification directory...
Reading files...
```

Package files are created in the current directory.

One warnings:

- the current directory and the source directory should not be parent/child or child/parent, it has not been tested that way.

This is the script (The PACKSIZELIMIT is the number of bytes, if DELETESOURCE is 1 then it will delete source files [well, you should also remove the # simbol before the "rm -f" line]):

```
#!/bin/bash

PACKSIZELIMIT=100000000
PACKPREFFIX="pack"
#PACKSUFFIX=$(date +"_%Y%m%d_%H%M")
PACKSUFFIX=""
DELETESOURCE=0


LISTFILE="packbatchlist.txt"
MANIFESTFILE="manifest.txt"
CHECKSUMFILE="checksums.txt"
VERIFYFILE="verifysums.txt"



if [ -d "$1" ]; then
  PACKCOUNTER=0
  PACKSIZE=0
  FILECOUNTER=0
  ALLFILECOUNTER=0
  cat /dev/null > $LISTFILE
  cat /dev/null > $MANIFESTFILE
  cat /dev/null > $CHECKSUMFILE
  cat /dev/null > $VERIFYFILE
  echo "Reading files..."
  TOTALFILES=$(find "$1" -type f | wc -l)
  echo "There are $TOTALFILES files to process..."
  find "$1" -type f | while read SOURCEFILE ; do
    let "FILECOUNTER+=1"
    let "ALLFILECOUNTER+=1"
    echo -ne "\r$ALLFILECOUNTER $FILECOUNTER $SOURCEFILE\e[K"
    THISFILESIZE=$(stat -c %s "$SOURCEFILE")
    let "PACKSIZE+=$THISFILESIZE"
    echo $SOURCEFILE >> $LISTFILE
    ls -l $SOURCEFILE >> $MANIFESTFILE
    sha1sum $SOURCEFILE >> $CHECKSUMFILE
    if [ $PACKSIZE -gt $PACKSIZELIMIT -o $ALLFILECOUNTER -eq $TOTALFILES ]; then
      echo
      echo $MANIFESTFILE >> $LISTFILE
      echo $CHECKSUMFILE >> $LISTFILE
      PACKFILENAME="$PACKPREFFIX$PACKCOUNTER$PACKSUFFIX.tar.gz"
      echo "Creating package ($PACKFILENAME) with $FILECOUNTER files, using $PACKSIZE bytes..."
      tar -cf - -T $LISTFILE | gzip -c > $PACKFILENAME
      echo "Preparing to verify package..."
      TEMPCHECKDIR=$(mktemp -d)
      tar xzf $PACKFILENAME -C $TEMPCHECKDIR
      if [ -r "$TEMPCHECKDIR/$CHECKSUMFILE" ] ; then
        cut -d " " -f 1 $TEMPCHECKDIR/$CHECKSUMFILE > $VERIFYFILE
        sort $VERIFYFILE > $TEMPCHECKDIR/$CHECKSUMFILE
        echo "Creating new checksums..."
        cat /dev/null > $VERIFYFILE
        find "$TEMPCHECKDIR" -type f | while read CHECKEDFILE ; do
          CHECKEDFILESHORT=$(basename $CHECKEDFILE)
          if [ "$CHECKEDFILESHORT" != "$MANIFESTFILE" -a "$CHECKEDFILESHORT" != "$CHECKSUMFILE" ] ; then
            sha1sum $CHECKEDFILE | cut -d " " -f 1 >> $VERIFYFILE
          fi
        done
        sort $VERIFYFILE -o $VERIFYFILE
        echo "Comparing checksums..."
        DIFFFILES=$(comm --nocheck-order -3 $TEMPCHECKDIR/$CHECKSUMFILE $VERIFYFILE | wc -l)
        if [ $DIFFFILES -gt 0 ] ; then
          echo "ERROR: Package failed verification!"
          exit 2
        else
          echo "Package verification OK."
          echo "Deleting temporary verification directory..."
          find "$TEMPCHECKDIR" -delete
          if [ "$DELETESOURCE" == "1" ] ; then
            echo "Deleting source files..."
            cat $LISTFILE | while read FILE2DEL ; do
              echo -ne "\rDeleting $FILE2DEL ... \e[K"
              #rm -f $FILE2DEL
            done
            echo -e "\rFiles deleted.\e[K"
          fi
        fi
      else
        echo "ERROR: Cannot find checksum file from package!"
        exit 1
      fi
      let "PACKCOUNTER+=1"
      PACKSIZE=0
      FILECOUNTER=0
      cat /dev/null > $LISTFILE
      cat /dev/null > $MANIFESTFILE
      cat /dev/null > $CHECKSUMFILE
      cat /dev/null > $VERIFYFILE
      echo "Reading files..."
    fi
  done
else 
  echo
  echo "Missing source directory"
  echo
fi   


rm -f $LISTFILE
rm -f $MANIFESTFILE
rm -f $CHECKSUMFILE
rm -f $VERIFYFILE
```

Comment: I don't even want to check if your code works. I will accept this as an answer just to appreciate the sheer amount of effort you put into this! Great effort!

Answer (score 2):

GNU split has a `-C` option which is like `-b` but doesn't break lines.

Comment: Poor, unhelpful answer. Compare yours with MV's. Don't assume people don't know how to read man pages.

Comment: The questioner had already researched `split -b` and found that it had a problem; all that needs to be done to fix that problem is change the `b` to a `C`. There really wasn't much else to add except that you have to be using GNU split. We may disagree about giving a man a fish vs. teaching a man to fish, but that giant shell script is more like reinventing the fish. But it's accepted... no use arguing about it.